# Radeon 4670 Card Has 2 DVI Outs But Only Works When One is used in Windows 7 x64

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have an ATI XFX Radeon 4670 1GB video card in a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 setup.  If I only use one monitor, all is well.  If I plug in a second DVI cable to the card, both monitors go dark.  I can get one or the other to display, but only when it is the only one plugged into the card.  I'm really hoping for a dual-monitor setup here as that was the point of the card.  I'm using ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series video drivers dated 11/24/09 (8.681.0.0) which are the latest from their site and are supposed to work with Vista or Windows 7 x64.

When the computer boots with both displays connected, both monitors display the inital BIOS and boot screens.  The Windows 7 splash screen also displays, but by the time it goes to the login screen, one monitor is offline.

Comment: Oh, and trying to reinstall either the 9.12 or 9.11 drivers results in the CATALYST Install Manager crashing:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: InstallManagerApp.exe
  Application Version: 3.0.750.0
  Application Timestamp: 4af194f1
  Fault Module Name: MFC80U.DLL
  Fault Module Version: 8.0.50727.1833
  Fault Module Timestamp: 482bb4a2

Answer (score 0):

> When the computer boots with both
>   displays connected, both monitors
>   display the inital bios and boot
>   screens.

sound pretty much like a driver problem alright, try an **[older driver](http://www.filehippo.com/download_ati_catalyst_vista_64/)**.

Comment: Thanks!  I grabbed 9.11 from the link you provided but it crashes when I try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop, click on "Screen Resolution."

You should see both monitors there, and a drop down list box labelled "Multiple Displays"...you should select something that makes sense for whatever setup you want, such as "Extend."

If you don't see both monitors there, there's a high chance that Molly7244's driver issue is in play.

Comment: Also there's a pretty good chance that you're using ATI and not nVidia. Oh snap!

Comment: Erm... the user asking this question hasn't been seen in over a year, and drivers have changed substantially since then. Not really worth answering at this point.

Comment: Oh snap, didn't even notice.